# Dockerizing a wodpress mutlisite - why am I not redirected to the installation page?

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, apache

I'm trying to dockerize a multisite wordpress,but I can't see what I did wrong.

I made a docker-compose file, when I run docker-compose up, volumes and containers are created and everything goes well, when I access the localhost:8085 all what I see is a blank page.

I tired deleting volumes, and tried building from the start but for some I always end up in the same situation.

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - wp-multisite
    restart: always
    environment:
      DB_HOST: localhost
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    ports: 
      - 3306:3306

  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: 'phpmyadmin:latest'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
        - 8090:80

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
        - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - 8085:80
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
      - ./wordpress/.htaccess:/var/www/html/.htaccess
    networks:
      - wp-multisite
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 1
      WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA:  |
        define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
        define('MULTISITE', true);
        define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
        define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost');
        define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
        define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
        define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

        define('WP_HOME', 'http://localhost');
        define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost');
        define( 'NOBLOGREDIRECT', '' );    

volumes:
  db_data:
  wordpress:

networks:
  wp-multisite:
```

The wordpress container logs says this:

```
Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using xxxxxxx.
Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
WordPress database error Table 'wordpress.wp_blogs' doesn't exist
```

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: You need to add data into database

Comment: What do you mean, what data??

Comment: It's mean your database is empty. `The error WordPress database error Table 'wordpress.wp_blogs' doesn't exist`

Comment: Yes of course it's empty, it should redirect me to the installation page first so that the tables can be created!!

Comment: Are you clear your volume  `- db_data:/var/lib/mysql-`  ?

Comment: I didn't understand the question

Comment: I see. You need check your docker volume in your db service:
 `
   volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
`

Comment: Sorry that doesn't make any sense there is nothing wrong with the volume

Comment: I think you need replace in docker compose file 

        define('WP_HOME', 'http://localhost');
        define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost');

with  define('WP_HOME', 'http://localhost:8085');
        define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost:8085');

Comment: That's not the problem, but thanks anyway